# Sending array of dictionaries as curl parameter

Tags: curl, command-line

I am trying to send an array of dictionaries as parameter of a curl request. I have an object that look like this :

```
{ "name" => "xxx", "age" => "xxx" }
```

I know that you can send arrays this way :

```
curl -X POST -d 'objects[]=xxx&objects[]=xxx' https://xxx.xx
```

But I do not know how to send dictionaries as content of the array. As a final result, I would like to access to params like this

Php :

```
$_POST["objects"]["name"]
```

Rails

```
params[:objects][:name]
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to achieve that. The solution I used was to send a JSON parameter and then serialize it from my backend.